# Can't get bitmoji image to display in ImageView from intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I'm using an intent in Android to list my app when I select a bitmoji in the Bitmoji app. It then should launch my app and display the bitmoji in an ImageView.

It launches my app fine, but the imageView is blank.

I get the following error:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bitstrips.imoji/cache/bitmoji-1441479250.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView mImageView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    }

}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    String selectedImagePath;
    selectedImagePath = getPath(imageUri);
    Toast.makeText(context, selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(imageUri!=null) {
        new imageWorkerTask().execute(selectedImagePath);
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{
    /*
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
    */
    return uri.getPath();
}

class imageWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... paths) {
        return decodeBitmapFromFile(paths[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromFile(String path) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    //options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
 }
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: I am able to load an image from a resource (from my drawable folder) into the imageView. It's specifically when I'm trying to get the image from another app(bitmoji) that the imageView doesn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add read permission into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I do have that in my AndroidManifest.xml, there must be some other issue...